# Suggest optimal algorithm to find min number of days to purchase all toys

Tags: algorithm

**Note: I am still looking for a fast solution. Two of the solutions below are wrong and the third one is terribly slow.**

I have N toys from 1....N. Each toy has an associated cost with it. You have to go on a shopping spree such that on a particular day, if you buy toy i, then the next toy you can buy on the same day should be i+1 or greater. Moreover, the **absolute** cost difference between any two consecutively bought toys should be greater than or equal to k. What is the minimum number of days can I buy all the toys.

I tried a greedy approach by starting with toy 1 first and then seeing how many toys can I buy on day 1. Then, I find the smallest i that I have not bought and start again from there.

Example:

```
Toys : 1 2  3  4 
Cost : 5 4 10 15
```

let k be 5

On day 1, buy 1,3, and 4
on day 2, buy toy 2

Thus, I can buy all toys in 2 days

Note greedy not work for below example: N = 151 and k = 42
the costs of the toys 1...N in that order are :

```
383 453 942 43 27 308 252 721 926 116 607 200 195 898 568 426 185 604 739 476 354 533 515 244 484 38 734 706 608 136 99 991 589 392 33 615 700 636 687 625 104 293 176 298 542 743 75 726 698 813 201 403 345 715 646 180 105 732 237 712 867 335 54 455 727 439 421 778 426 107 402 529 751 929 178 292 24 253 369 721 65 570 124 762 636 121 941 92 852 178 156 719 864 209 525 942 999 298 719 425 756 472 953 507 401 131 150 424 383 519 496 799 440 971 560 427 92 853 519 295 382 674 365 245 234 890 187 233 539 257 9 294 729 313 152 481 443 302 256 177 820 751 328 611 722 887 37 165 739 555 811
```

Comment: What language would you like that answer in?

Comment: @austincheney: Just the pseudo code works. Language is not a problem . I can easily code in C, C++, C#, SML, PHP, JS, Java, Scheme

Comment: @austincheney: would prefer java

Comment: **I SUGGEST YOU CHANGE THE CASE OF YOUR INITIAL DISCLAIMER AS IT REALLY COME ACROSS AS SOMEBODY SHOUTING IN YOUR FACE! THE FACT YOU ARE STILL LOOKING FOR A SOLUTION IS CLEAR BY THE LACK OF AN ACCEPTED ANSWER ANYHOW!!!** :O

Answer (score 6):

You can find the optimal solution by solving the asymmetric Travelling Salesman.

Consider each toy as a node, and build the complete directed graph (that is, add an edge between each pair of nodes). The edge has cost 1 (has to continue on next day) if the index is smaller or the cost of the target node is less than 5 plus the cost of the source node, and 0 otherwise. Now find the shortest path covering this graph without visiting a node twice - i.e., solve the Travelling Salesman.

This idea is not very fast (it is in NP), but should quickly give you a reference implementation.

Comment: This will NOT be a complete graph as if you buy toy i, you have to buy toy i+1 or greater. So, you solution is wrong

Comment: I think this is correct solution. For each pair of nodes A and B there are two edges either with costs 0 and 1 or 1 and 1. For any edge that goes from C (current) to N (next) the cost is 0 only if N comes after C AND abs(value(N)-value(C))>=5.

Comment: @thiton: You meantion that we have to find the shortest path covering this graph without visiting a node twice. However, according to TSP, the start node and the end node has to be the same . Thus, we have to visit a node twice. Is this a contradiction or am i missing something

Comment: @ZhangFeng: There is no contradiction since you can choose the start node arbitrarily (it is a closed path, after all). Choose the node with the lowest price as the start node, and delete the edge leading to this node from the closed path to get an open path covering all nodes. This is optimal since you are guaranteed to delete an edge with cost 1 (no way this node continued a shopping spree), which is also the highest cost.

Comment: @thiton: Do you know of a place where I can get a possible implementation of the tsp\

Comment: @ZhangFeng: [The wikipedia has some options.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Exact_algorithms)

Comment: @thiton: One last question. Refering to your suggestion above of deleting the edge leading to the node with lowest price, in summary, you mean, find the closed path using TSP and subtract 1 from the sum of the edges of this path

Comment: @ZhangFeng: Yes, exactly. This gives you an optimal solution, even though at large computational cost.

Answer (score 3):

This is not as difficult as ATSP. All you need to do is look for [increasing subsequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence).

Being a mathematician, the way I would solve the problem is to apply [RSK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson%E2%80%93Schensted_correspondence) to get a pair of [Young tableaux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_tableau), then the answer for how many days is the height of the tableau and the rows of the second tableau tell you what to purchase on which day.

The idea is to do [Schensted insertion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson%E2%80%93Schensted_correspondence#Insertion) on the cost sequence `c`. For the example you gave, `c = (5, 4, 10, 15)`, the insertion goes like this:

Step 1: Insert `c[1] = 5`

```
P = 5
```

Step 2: Insert `c[2] = 4`

```
    5
P = 4
```

Step 3: Insert `c[3] = 10`

```
    5
P = 4 10
```

Step 4: Insert `c[4] = 15`

```
    5
P = 4 10 15
```

The idea is that you insert the entries of `c` into `P` one at a time. When inserting `c[i]` into row `j`:

- if `c[i]` is bigger than the largest element in the row, add it to the end of the row;
- otherwise, find the leftmost entry in row `j` that is larger than `c[i]`, call it `k`, and replace `k` with `c[i]` then insert `k` into row `j+1`.

`P` is an array where the lengths of the rows are weakly decreasing and The entries in each of row `P` (these are the costs) weakly increase. The number of rows is the number of days it will take.

For a more elaborate example (made by generating 9 random numbers)

```
      1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
c = [ 5  4 16  7 11  4 13  6  5]

     16
      7 
      5  6 11 
P =   4  4  5 13
```

So the best possible solution takes 4 days, buying 4 items on day 1, 3 on day 2, 1 on day 3, and 1 on day 4.

---

To handle the additional constraint that consecutive costs must increase by at least `k` involves redefining the (partial) order on costs. Say that `c[i] <k< c[j]` if and only if `c[j]-c[i] >= k` in the usual ordering on numbers. The above algorithm works for partial orders as well as total orders.

Comment: I understand the first part of your solution. However, I do not understand how to account for the additional constraint that the absolute difference between any two consecutive costs must be >=k. Can you please give me an example incorporating this constraint

Comment: One more thing: the requirement is NOT that consecutive costs should increase by atleast k. the requirement is that the absolute difference between consecutive cost should be atleast k

Comment: @ZhangFeng For full details, please see [this paper](http://csit.am/2009/proceedings/2DMCA/5.pdf)

Comment: Can you please give me a small example with the constraint included. I am really short on time for this one. Thanks

Comment: @ZhangFeng: I think this solution is incorrect because it does not consider the absolute cost difference. It just says that the cost shd be increasing!

Comment: @PengOne: Wrong solution. Does not adhere to constraints. Read above why

Answer (score 1):

I somewhat feel that a greedy approach would give a fairly good result.

I think your approach is not optimal just because you always pick toy 1 to start while you should really pick the least expensive toy. Doing so would give you the most room to move to the next toy.

Each move being the least expensive one, it is just DFS problem where you always follow the least expensive path constrained by k.

Comment: Your solution is wrong. Let us say toys are  1, 2 ,3, and 4 and their costs are 5,4,3,2 respectively. According to your solution, i will take 4 days as i will buy toy 4 on day 1 (least expensive) and so one. However, according to my solution, I will just take 1 day if I begin with toy 1

Comment: You are right. I was actually mistaken thinking Matroid could be applied here. I missed the fact that there is some ordering involved with your next choice...